# ECMA script package import in Jest: dynamic import not working

Tags: ecmascript-6, jestjs

Getting the error when trying to load ecma script packages in my e2e tests. This works fine when running npm run start:

```
import { Provider } from '@nestjs/common';

export const P_RETRY_PACKAGE_NAME = 'p-retry';

export interface PRetryEsmPackage {
  <T>(input: (attemptCount: number) => PromiseLike<T> | T, options?: Record<string, unknown>): Promise<T>;
}

export const PRetryPackageProvider: Provider = {
  provide: P_RETRY_PACKAGE_NAME,
  useFactory: async () => {
    try {
      const pRetryPkg = await import(P_RETRY_PACKAGE_NAME);
      return pRetryPkg.default as PRetryEsmPackage;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Failed to load ${P_RETRY_PACKAGE_NAME}: ${error.message}`);
      throw error; // Re-throwing to ensure the provider fails if it's essential
    }
  },
};
```

```
    TypeError: A dynamic import callback was not specified.

      11 |   useFactory: async () => {
      12 |     try {
    > 13 |       const pRetryPkg = await import(P_RETRY_PACKAGE_NAME);


{
  code: "ERR_VM_DYNAMIC_IMPORT_CALLBACK_MISSING",
}
```

I found the jest docs here: https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules and set NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules

and here's the relevant parts of tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext"
  }
}
```

Any suggestions for where/how to debug further would be appreciated